# "Feed a cold, starve a fever"?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, common-cold

Is there any truth behind this phrase? I was always skeptical and figured that the body needed energy from food to fight whatever illness it may have.

I have even heard people say it in reverse: "Feed a fever, starve a cold"!

So which is it?

> Feed a fever and a cold;
>
> Feed a fever, starve a cold;
>
> Feed a cold, starve a fever;
>
> or
>
> Starve a fever, starve a cold?

Comment: got a cold right now, and was searching for *exactly this*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Albert Einstein Healthcare Network](http://healthlibrary.epnet.com/GetContent.aspx?token=9076b2c9-0730-4f1a-b6fa-5a462bb0a011&chunkiid=156982):

> **For the claim:**
>   
> A Dutch research team conducted a small, [preliminary study](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn1777-feed-a-cold-starve-a-fever-may-be-right.html) that provides some indirect support for the old myth. They found that the subjects’ immune systems responded differently under the conditions of feeding versus starvation.
>
> While these are intriguing findings, they say little about how a person suffering from a cold or a fever can expect to actually feel when fed or starved. Although the study was small and inconclusive, the idea that food consumption may have a short-lived effect on the immune system is a new one, as previous studies have focused on more long-term effects.
>
> **Against the claim**:
>   
> Current medical opinion puts the “feed a cold, starve a fever” maxim in the same category as other medical advice from the Middle Ages–false and maybe even dangerous!
>
> An infection–particularly one associated with fevers– is no time to deny your body the nutrients and fluids it needs. Like any bodily system, the immune system requires energy to function properly.
>
> **Whether you’re thirsty or not, drink plenty of fluids. And, if you’re hungry–eat!**

From [Duke Health](http://www.dukehealth.org/health_library/health_articles/feed_a_cold):

> Although a few small-scale studies
>   have suggested that “feed a cold,
>   starve a fever” loosely represents
>   sound medical advice, **Duke medical
>   experts caution against putting too
>   much faith in the adage**.

From the [European
Food Information Council](http://www.eufic.org/web/page.asp?cust=1&lng=en&page=FAQ&faqid=215):

> **You do not need to do either.** Instead
>   it's better to follow your appetite,
>   although if you are sweating a lot
>   [...] it is really
>   important to increase your fluid
>   intake to avoid becoming dehydrated.
>
> **The stress of illness can increase protein demands.**
>   
>  Other important nutrients needed for the production of "germ-gobbling" cells in the immune system are zinc (in seafood and red meat) plus folic acid and pro-vitamin A (beta carotene) in broccoli, spinach and carrots.

More Sources that say **the claim has little merit**:

- [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/02/13/health/13real.html)
- [ABC News - Health](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/ColdandFluQuestions/story?id=5678126)
- [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/cold-guide/starve-cold-feed-fever)
- [Discovery - Fit & Health](http://health.howstuffworks.com/diseases-conditions/cold-flu/starve-a-fever.htm)

Comment: But what happens when your cold gives you a fever?  Oh yeah, spontaneous combustion!